# git-tfs what URI to use for TFS for list-remote-branches

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

We have a TFS Source Control system that we've been using for years. New management and common sense says we need to move to git going forward.

SO, trying git-tfs with no luck.  The closest I get is "TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundations Server: http://server:8080/tfs/Web Sites/Main Content Site/Main Content Site TEam/_versionControl."

Here's the command I'm attempting:
git-tfs list-remote-branches http://tfs-server-url:8080/tfs/Web%20Sites/Main%20Content%20Site/Main%20Content%20Site%20Team/_versionControl -u=domain/username -p=password

With tfs-server-url being the url of our tfs server and domain being our local domain and username being my username on tfs and password being my password on tfs.

What am I missing about the syntax???

BTW, if I navigate to http://tfs-server-url:8080/tfs/Web%20Sites/Main%20Content%20Site/Main%20Content%20Site%20Team/_versionControl in my browser, I see all our branches for the "$/Main Content Site" tfs project.

PS: also at the end of the git-tfs output are two lines that say:
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be the URL to your team project collection. In your case, `http://server:8080/tfs/Web Sites/`.

You then specify a branch to clone, which would be `$/Main Content Site/SomeBranch`.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I had tried that url, but I guess that was before I had put in the username and password....  Next I'll try a clone of one of the branches that was returned...